# Google Webmaster Tools says sitemap has error, it doesn't

Tags: xml, sitemap, google-search-console

So a client has this autogenerated sitemap: http://nordwest-najad.se/sitemap.xml
And when I try to add it to google webmaster tools I get this error:

```
Missing XML tag
This required tag is missing. Please add it and resubmit.
```

The problem is that the xml tag is there and there is nothing wrong with the document.
I have validated the document with these sites:
http://www.validome.org/google/
http://sitemapxml.net/sitemap-validator.php
http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html
And all three sites says that there is no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668

Your Sitemap file must specify the following XML namespace: xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9".

Comment: I can't find anything about <news:news> being a proper supported XML tag.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe there is a difference between a news sitemap and a web sitemap. So I can't add news in this sitemap. http://support.google.com/news/publisher/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74288&topic=2527688&ctx=topic

Comment: There is, I am learning things as well.  <publication> is a required field for <news>.  http://support.google.com/news/publisher/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74288&topic=2527688&ctx=topic so adding news in the sitemap is fine

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it for my case

I checked [www.dhakalist.com/sitemap.xm](http://www.dhakalist.com/sitemap.xml)l was working but not [dhakalist.com/sitemap.xml](http://dhakalist.com/sitemap.xml)

so i added these lines in my .htaccess file and problem solved.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now google is taking sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Google webmaster tool showing right error because you are completely missing your XML tag.
Because your starting line

“http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">” have error.

Change it with

http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

This is necessary for validating the process that defines the elements and attributes. You can define in your sitemap file according to XML schema guidelines.